# Last seen is showing the time difference?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I got a message from one number at 10.30 but it is showing the last seen as 9.30.Why?

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when

1.User wrote the message when he/she was offline and when user turned on Mobile data or wifi then whatsapp automatically sends message even if whatsapp interface is not opened.
Last seen updates when the user opens the interface.

2.There may be some network issues causing whatsapp to not update last seen but messages being send but late.

3.There are many modded versions of whatsapp in which user can freeze the last seen